# Family Tree JSON Generator PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, tree

I would like to achieve JSON format as such

```
    [{"name": "Niclas Superlongsurname",
  "class": "male node-item",
  "textClass": "emphasis",

  "marriages": [{

      "spouse": {
          "name": "Iliana",
          "class": "female"
      },
      "children": [{
          "name": "James",
          "class": "male",
          "marriages": [{
              "spouse": {
              "name": "Alexandra",
              "class": "female"
          },
      "children": [{
          "name": "Eric",
          "class": "male",
          "marriages": [{
            "spouse": {
              "name": "Eva",
              "class": "female"
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "Jane",
          "class": "female"
        }, {
          "name": "Jasper",
          "class": "male"
        }, {
          "name": "Emma",
          "class": "female"
        }, {
          "name": "Julia",
          "class": "female"
        }, {
          "name": "Jessica",
          "class": "female"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
},{
    "name": "Same level as Niclas",
    "class": "male",
}]
```

The database table, I Have something like

```
id | name | userID | relatedID | parentID | level
1     Jon       1        0           3        6
2     Jan       1        1           0        6
3     Mum       1        0           0        5
```

UserID is used for distinguishing user from other families.
RelatedID is used for spouse purpose.
ParentID is used for parents.

Im trying to achieve this in recursive but fail at the first level only. Could someone help me out in the recursion part?

```
$currentLvl = $result[0]["level"];
        foreach($result as $id => $val)
        {

            // if(!in_array($val["relationshipID"], $doneArr))


            //parent
            if($val["parentID"] > 0)
            {
                $mainParentIndex = array_search($val["parentID"],  array_column($relationshipArray, 'id')); // $key = 2;
                $relationshipArray[$mainParentIndex]["marriages"][0]["children"][$childrenIndex]["name"] = $val["relationshipName"];
                $relationshipArray[$mainParentIndex]["marriages"][0]["children"][$childrenIndex]["class"] = strtolower($val["relationshipGender"]);     
                $relationshipArray[$mainParentIndex]["marriages"][0]["children"][$childrenIndex]["id"] = strtolower($val["relationshipID"]);        
                $childrenIndex++;


                //start


                //end

            }   
            else{
                // {
                if($val["relatedID"] == 0 && $val["parentID"] == 0)
                {
                    $relationshipArray[$ownSiblingsIndex]["name"] = $val["relationshipName"];
                    $relationshipArray[$ownSiblingsIndex]["class"] = strtolower($val["relationshipGender"]);    
                    $relationshipArray[$ownSiblingsIndex]["id"] = $val["relationshipID"];   
                    $doneArr[] = $val["relationshipID"];
                    $ownSiblingsIndex++;
                }


                //is a spouse
                if($val["relatedID"] > 0)
                { 
                    $mainSpouseIndex = array_search($val["relatedID"],  array_column($relationshipArray, 'id')); // $key = 2;
                    //echo $val["relationshipID"]."-".$val["relatedID"]."- ".$mainSpouseIndex."<br>";   
                    $relationshipArray[$mainSpouseIndex]["marriages"][0]["spouse"]["name"] = $val["relationshipName"];
                    $relationshipArray[$mainSpouseIndex]["marriages"][0]["spouse"]["class"] = strtolower($val["relationshipGender"]);
                    $relationshipArray[$mainSpouseIndex]["marriages"][0]["spouse"]["id"] = $val["relationshipID"];  
                    $doneArr[] = $val["relationshipID"];
                    $removeArr[] = $val["relationshipID"];
                }
            }
```

EDIT: database 
[image: database structure & data]

Comment: what does the 'level' field mean? can you provide like some more rows of data to test it out for good?

Comment: level is a column for me to determine how many level/depth in the family. Eg. There would be up to 4 level above <me> and 4 level below <me>. So <me> would be level 5. Dad and mum would be level 4. My sons and daughter would be level 6. Let me